# Why doesn't sql compare times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am comparing these 2 times if it is smaller or greater than each other but it doesn't. Why ?

```
 if(@OpeningTime < @ExpiryTime)
      Begin
            Raiserror('Opening time cannot be smaller than expiry time', 16,10);
            return
      End
```

both are of type varchar(10)

time passed are like 10:00am and 11:00am

Comment: Why are you storing these as `varchar` when SQL Server has perfectly functional types such as `time`?

Comment: SQL does compare times, you're telling it to compare 2 strings.

Comment: from where & how this both variables OpeningTime & ExpiryTime get value?

Answer (score 9):

What you are actually doing is comparing strings, you need to convert your `VARCHAR` to `TIME` first then compare them.

```
IF ( CONVERT(TIME, @OpeningTime) < CONVERT(TIME, @ExpiryTime) )
```

Comment: Is `CONVERT` guaranteed to work for '10:00am'? Here in Germany for instance this is no valid time, as we use the 24 hour format only. Unfortuanatly I have no SQL Server here to try it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just tested on my local machine (running sql server 2012) and I got 10:00:00.0000000 when converting '10:00AM' and 22:00:00.0000000 for '10:00PM' However personally I am a fan of 24 times anyway - less room for error/misinterpretation

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just as a followup i found that the datetime style formats 109 and 130 are specific for outputting the 12 hour format.

Comment: This format is officialy taken in count, you can go for it without problems